# Default highlighting color in Document Viewer

Tags: pdf

The default color for annotating PDFs in Document Viewer is pale yellow. How to change this default color?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way at this time to change the default colour, you can however change the colour of a single existing annotation by right it clicking and selecting "annotation properties".

If you'd like more options you can try the okular pdf reader which has a more powerful annotation system.

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** on the highlighted text/object, you should get a new window with several options one of them is `Annotation Properties...` **Select it** and you can change the color of your highlighted text.

Comment: Not as such a correct answer. This changes the color after the note has been created. It does not change the default color for a new note.